# Name page template properly

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I have custom taxonomy in place which builds URL that way:
**domain/course/course-name/lesson**

Course - is a custom post type.

I am facing difficulty to reach the right template for lessons. I've tried "page-course.php" but it doesn't work.

How should I call template for lessons?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you trying to create a template that will be used for all posts in your 'course' CPT? Try calling your template `single-course.php'

Comment: Also, I don't know if you've come across this before, but this link is really helpful for template hierarchy, https://wphierarchy.com

Comment: What is the lesson in your site. Is it custom taxonomy?

Answer (score 1):

Taking a look at the [template hierarchy](https://wphierarchy.com/), it says you should use `single-course.php`. The template hierarchy lists how. WP decides which template to load, and all the valid values